# what is better placement for navigation arrows & call to action button?

Tags: user-expectation

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Please check given image.
Up & down arrows are used for navigation. there is one more CTA "Confirm"

Comment: Could you clarify your point?

Comment: Where is the down arrow? Maybe show an image with both arrows in place.

Comment: here bcoz there is confirm button down arrow will not come..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm understanding the case correctly.

Between what are you navigating with the arrow keys?
The button with the arrow, is it fixed there?

I'd probably put the button here, since it's more prominent and better fitting the design.

Edit: The back-button could go here.

Comment: Arrows are working like previous & next buttons to go back & next of the page.And in the page i have given there is one more action coming which is confirm where use has to confirm without that he cant move next.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it. But the little round (floating) button with the up-arrow on the right, what is it for? If you need an extra level of security, you could also add a checkbox to activate the button.

Comment: that up arrow is to take to previous page.....why to add checkbox?

Comment: arrow: From what I've seen so far this could be confusing. Do you have an animation, scrolling the page upwards of why are you using an up-arrow?
checkbox: Just if you need that extra layer of security an make sure the user didn't click accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'Confirm' is the primary CTA. It should be placed at the most prominent location.

Up arrows doesn't seem useful for this particular page.
[image]

Comment: And how to navigate to previous screen?

Comment: I didn't notice there are multiple page under the same tab. In that case '<BACK' button could be added to the top left or under the confirm but only as a text button.